# Run totally silent rsync?

Tags: ssh, rsync

I have a cronjob that runs hourly, and is totally silent unless something goes wrong. Well ... almost ...

A part of the job is

```
rsync --del -Cacqrz public/. user@host.example.com:/target/path
```

This always prints "logged in". How can I make it stop? (Short of 'grep -v' ;-)

I don't get the "logged in" message if I do things like

```
ssh user@host.example.com ls
```

The transport is, of course, ssh (using keys).

Source host is either OSX or Ubuntu (tried both, same behavior).
Target host is Linux of some flavor.

Comment: You can change the default verbosity of ssh in ~/.ssh/config or globally in ssh_config (location varies with distro).

Answer (score 22):

`quiet` option should do that:

`-q, --quiet                 suppress non-error messages`

Comment: I'm using the rsync "-q", which successfully stifles a lot of blather, but it's not stopping this one message (which does not look like a problem to me). I think the un-stifled message comes from ssh/scp, but I don't have direct access to that command line. So I don't see how your suggestion helps.

Comment: You can modify ssh options:  `rsync -e 'ssh -q'` will stop ssh from outputting the ssh banner, for example.

Answer (score 8):

You can redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null` with something like:

```
<command> 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

Comment: ...and then check the return code from `rsync` (`$?`) -- if it's non-zero something went wrong and you have to handle that error gracefully.

Comment: @voretaq7 Meh, it's friday. I'm drinking beer. Can't think about such things. :)

Comment: Error Checking? ***AIN'T NOBODY GOT TIME FOR THAT!***